# How to detect clicks ,having listview inside another listview

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

Hi i am having a list l which contain L1 -> B2 -> B3 -> L2

B is button , l is list

L1 contains B1 -> B2
L2 contains B4 -> B5

complete list looks like  B1->B2->B3->B4->B5

how to differentiate click on B1 and B4

Answer (score 0):

@Harsh just use Expandable ListView for your work. It will ease all your click/selection related work!
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Comment: Cant we do this without using Expandable listview ?

Comment: @HarshMiddha have you tried something?Show me your code